# JWPlayer .onError triggered when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, error-handling, jwplayer, onerror

I have a .onError function on my player, which by itself is fine.
However, the problem is when the page is refreshed (user action) the .onError action fired, any way to avoid it?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running this?

Comment: I'll try to make one for you but basically what happens is that when you press refresh, player troughs - error loading media, file could not be played - and thus trigger error handler. Could it be because the player gets playlist data from the page itself? I thought that it would store it in "itself" somehow and not reference it all the time because otherwise it is logical that after elements are destroyed on the page the player can't find what to play...

Comment: I have an answer for this, I will post it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this under your player's closing <script> tag:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = stopPlayers;
function stopPlayers(){
     jwplayer().stop(true);
}
</script>
```